# how to covert fahrenheit temperature to celcius and rainfall inches to centimeter

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a two table in my  oracle database and i have a  below question to solve as i am beginner i am not getting solution please resolve it.

Execute a query to display each city’s monthly temperature in Celsius and rainfall in Centimeter.

[station table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8uUd.jpg)

[stats table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nbmoa.jpg)

i dont have any idea how to covert the temperature as i am beginner in sql.

Comment: 'i dont have any idea how to covert the temperature' - but you do know the formula right?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the SQL because unit conversion is not related to SQL in any way. People were able to perform these conversions two hundred years ago when there were no SQL and no computers at all

Answer (score 0):

As there are 2 tables, you should **join** them on a common column (that's `id`) and apply algorithms to convert

- Fahrenheit to Celsius (subtract 32 and multiply by 5/9)
- inches to centimeters (multiply by 2.54)

Sample data:

```
SQL> with
  2  cities (id, city) as
  3    (select 13, 'Phoenix' from dual union all
  4     select 44, 'Denver'  from dual union all
  5     select 66, 'Caribou' from dual
  6    ),
  7  stats (id, month, temp_f, rain_i) as
  8    (select 13, 1, 57.4, 0.31 from dual union all
  9     select 44, 1, 27.3, 0.18 from dual
 10    )
```

Query:

```
 11  select c.id, c.city, s.month,
 12    --
 13    s.temp_f,
 14    round((s.temp_f - 32) * 5/9, 1) temp_c,
 15    --
 16    s.rain_i,
 17    round(s.rain_i * 2.54, 2) rain_cm
 18  from cities c left join stats s on s.id = c.id
 19  order by c.id, s.month;

        ID CITY         MONTH     TEMP_F     TEMP_C     RAIN_I    RAIN_CM
---------- ------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        13 Phoenix          1       57,4       14,1        ,31        ,79
        44 Denver           1       27,3       -2,6        ,18        ,46
        66 Caribou

SQL>
```

Comment: getting error from keyword not found where expected when i am trying above code

Comment: I'm, obviously, not. Which database do you use? Which version? Edit original question and post your own SQL*Plus session or screenshot which shows tool you have, query you ran and the outcome.

Comment: i have to write same as it is u written or just query part

Comment: Just query part. If table and/or column names differ, fix them first!

Comment: i write just query part and fix the table name column name also but its showing error from keyword not found where ecpected

Comment: SELECT st.ID, st.CITY, s.MONTH,
s.TEMP_F,
 ROUND(s.TEMP_F - 32)* 5/9, 1) TEMP_C,
s.RAIN_I,
 ROUND(s.RAIN_I *2.54, 2) RAIN_C
FROM Station st
 left Join STATS s
 on s.ID = st.Id
 order by st.Id, s.MOnth;

Comment: The 1st ROUND function has to have **two** opening brackets. You have only one.

Comment: ohh sorry its a tiny mistake from me . now done thanks.